# Open source OCR tool available in the market

Tags: .net, ocr

Is there any open source OCR library written in .NET, or written in any language but can be used in an ASP.NET application?
Or is there any open source OCR API available in the market for image to tabular formats ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Tessnet](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet/).

Tessnet is C++/CLI .NET Wrapper for tessdll (and [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)) for .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) and although it has no native .net bindings, it's pretty complete.

The "one to watch" is [OCRopus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) - A Google-sponsored effort that isn't ready for production work yet.

Comment: OCROpus can use the Tesseract engine, and does some layout analysis and other image pre-processing.

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, there is also [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/). Not tried.

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract OCR was developed by HP and open sourced, I believe.  I'm not sure how good the quality is.

Answer (score 1):

As the others are writing Tesseract is a good open source OCR implementation.

Eventhough it is good it is only an OCR engine. It does not do layout detection. If your input is not pure text you could have to figure out the layout yourself.