# Convert PDF to text file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ocr

I have a Scanned PDF Files , i need a VB.net Source Code which convert that scanned PDF to text Format.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the scanned file will not have the text but an image so you have to look at an OCR tool to get the text out.

There are several OCR libraries out there like

[Open source OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196918/open-source-ocr)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085/free-ocr-library

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://snipt.org/lOgh/ - it's in C# (should be relatively easy to rewrite in VB.NET), and uses a hosted OCR solution accessible through an API